# Will requests get lost during initialization of Node.JS app on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a Facebook Messenger bot written with Node.JS. Currently, it initializes the database (and cache) before initializing Express and receiving requests. I wonder if some requests are sent during initialization, will they get lost?

I'm using Heroku, it that matters.

Answer (score 0):

For free or hobby dyno in heroku there is no zero-downtime setup or preboot as a feature available. While deployment, your Node.js dyno will not serve
the incoming request from the point it restarts the process on that dyno till your server is running successfully on the specified port.

If you have zero-downtime setup already, then your requests will be served by
previous deployed instance unless the new one is spawn and ready to serve.

here is reference link for more info. on [zero-downtime heroku](https://sophieau.com/article/zero-downtime-heroku/)

Comment: I'm using Hobby dyno. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I didn't find anything till date.. The zero-downtime happens because of preboot() feature(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot) . This feature is only provided in standard plans(https://www.heroku.com/pricing). Basically in background heroku handles your work on another dyno while making sure your deployment is successful on current one. Running dynos with such concurrency feature is not allowed in hobby.